# Open multiple remote services in my windows

Tags: windows, windows-service

I want to manage on remote services of multiple servers.

I find the way to remote control services, but every time i want to switch servers i must re-enter the machine name.
Is possible to find a way/program, with a list of multiple machines and just with a click go to the services?

[image]

Comment: The server manager that comes with newer Windows versions (2012 and above) is quite good at this.

Comment: The Windows Server Versions are u saying? I want described behaviour in Win 10 pro. Is possible? maybe with a program?

Comment: [RSAT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) is also available for the desktop variants of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Server Manager, also available on Windows 10 Enterprise, can do this. Add all the servers to the manger and then go to Services on the dashboard.
[image]